Should OpenTelemetry AddSqlClientInstrumentation work with Azure functions?
I have an azure function running in the isolated worker process locally. My intention is to use the OpenTelemetry contrib packages rather than the built in features with the functions runtime, as I intend to integrate with OpenTelemtry.
From what I can tell .AddSqlClientInstrumentation() from OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient
Should trace SQL calls when using Microsoft.Data.SQLClient, of which the output bindings in Azure Functions appear to be using.
However I do not see any evidence of it working.
Is the OpenTelemetry package compatible with Azure Functions SQL output binding when using isolated functions?
I can see HttpClient instrumentation working fine, so in general I have OpenTelemetry packages configured ok.
My guess is that the extensions work in the host worker process, rather than the application worker process? But reading through the extension lifecycle docs, I cannot confirm that for sure, as they don't highlight it directly.
EDIT
Some additional context to illustrate what I am looking to achieve.
p.s. I'm less interested in problem solving the code, more whether the architecture of the Sql instrumentation libraries have any issues working in the azure functions runtime. But I certainly see the benefit of listing the code to add more context (thanks for the feedback).
var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {

        services.AddOpenTelemetry()
            .ConfigureResource(resource => resource.AddService(serviceName))
            .WithTracing(tracing => tracing
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddSqlClientInstrumentation(options => options.SetDbStatementForText = true)
                .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                .AddConsoleExporter()
                .AddAzureMonitorTraceExporter(options => options.ConnectionString = "XXX")
                );

    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.AddOpenTelemetry(options => options
                .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService(serviceName))
                .AddAzureMonitorLogExporter(options => options.ConnectionString = "XXX")
                .AddConsoleExporter());
    })
    .UseDefaultServiceProvider(x => x.ValidateOnBuild = true);

var host = builder.Build();

host.Run();

I have the following package references:
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.Exporter" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Sql" Version="3.0.534" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.3-preview2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient" Version="1.9.0-beta.1" />

And the following in the host.json, notably I have also been toying with appinsights native integration as well as OpenTelemetry, I did wonder whether appinsights might be consuming it and not allowing OpenTelemtry libraries to get the telemetry, but I can't imagine it's architected like that.
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true,
            "enableDependencyTracking": true,    
            "dependencyTrackingOptions": {
                "enableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation": true
            }
        }
    },
    "logLevel": {
        "default": "Information"
    },
    "telemetryMode": "openTelemetry"
}

EDIT 2:
I'm using azure functions output bindings i.e. via decorating the returned type with SqlOutput.
 public class NewUserOutputBinding
    {

        [SqlOutput("dbo.Users", connectionStringSetting: "SqlConnectionString")]
        public required User User { get; set; }

        [HttpResult]
        public required IActionResult HttpResponse { get; set; }

    }


The sqlclient instrumentation hooks into the eventsource that sql client produces, I don't believe that's different in Azure Functions

My recommendation would be to update the question with the setup code  and the code you use to call sql.

Thanks for the feedback @MartinDotNet I've added more context.

The way Microsoft.Data.SqlClient works isn't affected by Azure Functions. Whether you see any traces depends on whether the OTEL exporters are correctly configured. The App Insights JSON config you posted don't affect tracing at all, only the AppInsights log sink.

How did you determine that tracing doesn't work? Have you checked the console output? Do you see no traces in Azure Monitor or are the SQL traces the only thing missing? Does your application execute any SQL Server calls? Traces won't get generated until a SqlConnection is actually opened and used.

What happens when you run the same code locally (without the Azure Monitor exporter)? What does the Console output look then? You can export to a local application like the .NET Aspire Standalone Dashboard or OTEL Desktop Viewer to see traces locally before deploying to Azure, using the OTLP Exporter

Also note that the Azure Monitor OTEL docs enable Azure Monitor at the root with builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry().UseAzureMonitor();. The docs show how to combine Azure Monitor with OTLP exporter as an extra target. Despite the blurb it's not just for convenience - how else are you going to develop locally?

Great questions @PanagiotisKanavos I've added the SQL binding code, I can see the rows being written to the table*. The reason I believe it's not working as I cannot see it in the telemetry in the console output.
I added Azure Monitor simply because the console was becoming a pain to scan through, that's a good idea to use another local tool like aspire.
*I'm going to double check this now, now saying it "out loud", in case I caused a regression experimenting too much.

Double checked the SQL table writing, and it's okay. My theory is that the azure functions output binding is running in the host process which the open telemetry setup in my code doesn't have access to.

Now I get it - you're asking how to use OTEL to monitor the host as well and more specifically the SQL Output extension. The problem is the extension, which hasn't been updated in 1 year. OTEL Monitoring is supported with some extra configuration, the Functions Worker repo shows ActivitySource and Activity are used extensively, and the "new" extensions use it. SQL Output doesn't

When I say SQL Output doesn't use ActivitySource, I mean the entire Azure Functions SQL Extension repo has no code results for Activity or ActivitySource.

Good thinking about ActivitySource @PanagiotisKanavos . My understanding that the Sql instrumentation was instead listening for diagnostic events and then translating them into Activity etc. When looking at: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-contrib/blob/2b9c80f1cec0bbdfaec57ac48ba1434bd5d8fad4/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient/SqlClientInstrumentation.cs#L23

Ah, I may have answered my own question. DiagnosticListener probably isn't going to work in isolated worker processes, assuming that the Sql output binding is actually run in the func host?

I'm considering I may need a func host extension https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/wiki/Extension-startup-hook which I came across today. But I'm still intrigued to whether it's possible just in the regular code.

So it looks like it's working with typical SqlCommand, but not OutputBindings

I've been trying to reverse engineer the worker code and bindings, so far I think it is in fact running in the same process (which disproves my theory about DiagnosticListener). I think the worker and user code is one process and the host is another, but unfortunately I'm having trouble with VSCode's debugger in a devcontainer, so can't step all the way through to be certain.
